# Adding object to list without calling destructor

Tags: c++11, vector, destructor

I want to add a `Foo` object to a `std::vector` but I don't want to create a temporary object to add to the vector because that would call `Foo::~Foo()` once the temporary object goes out of scope. Do I have to use `new` and make the vector store Foo pointers, or is there another way?

What I **don't** want to do:

```
void FooHandler::AddFoo(int a, int b, int c) {
    Foo foo(a, b, c);
    vectorOfFoos.push_back(foo);
} //foo goes out of scope so Foo::~Foo() is called
```

Would these work?

```
//Foo has an implicit constructor which takes a FooSettings object
struct FooSettings {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void FooHandler::AddFoo(int a, int b, int c) {
    vectorOfFoos.push_back(Foo(a, b, c));
} //is Foo::~Foo() called here?

void FooHandler::AddFoo(FooSettings settings) {
    vectorOfFoos.push_back(settings);
} //is Foo::~Foo() called here?
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you not want `Foo`s destructor to be called?

Comment: @ChrisDrew `Foo` is actually a wrapper around some functions from a C library. `Foo::Foo()` constructor uses a function from this library which creates a dynamic pointer, while `Foo::~Foo()` destructor cleans up that pointer. Therefore, calling the destructor from any copy of a `Foo` instance would delete the dynamic pointer.

Comment: @Tagglink that sounds like the copy constructor for `Foo` is broken. Destroying a copy shouldn't generally delete some resource in another object. I'd suggest using `std::unique_ptr` rather than managing the resource manually.

Comment: @TartanLlama The thing with a smart pointer is that I need to invoke a certain function from the library to clean up the dynamic pointer rather than just use `delete`. In the constructor I'm doing `thingPtr = LIB_CreateThing(...)` while in the destructor I'm doing `LIB_DestroyThing(thingPtr)`.

Comment: @Tagglink `std::unique_ptr` lets you supply a custom deleter for situations like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your solutions will involve the creation of a temporary. You can use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead of `push_back` to construct the `Foo` instance in-place rather than copying it in to the vector.

```
void FooHandler::AddFoo(int a, int b, int c) {
    vectorOfFoos.emplace_back(a,b,c);
}
```